# How to transfer a text (url) from raspberry pi to my laptop remotely

Tags: python, ssh, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I have a raspberry pi mounted on my RC drone. It scans a QR code and gets the URL of a website by processing the QR code. I did that part. Now I need to send that url(text) to my laptop and open that on a web browser remotely. I am not allowed to touch the laptop after setting it up once. 
How can this be done?
Using SSH?
or 
I was thinking that I could write that url to notepad.pw/unique and my laptop then opens notepad.pw/unique , gets the url by scraping it, then runs it on webbrowser.

Answer (score 1):

A simple restful server seems to suit for your situation.

The following is implemented by flask

** server.py **

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    fun_dict = {
    'get_QR_code':'/get_qr_content'
}
return jsonify(fun_dict)


@app.route('/get_qr_content')
def get_qr_content():
    return YOUR_QRCODE_CONTENT

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

**# python server.py**

Now you can get YOUR_QRCODE_CONTENT through **curl**, **python request.get** whatever method to access http content.

Or just type in your browser

http://0.0.0.0/get_qr_content

Note: 0.0.0.0 is assume your device and laptop both in the same LAN. If not, you have to setup an ip address let both side is able to ping each other.

Comment: Thanks. I ultimately did it using socket module in python.